# Why following javascript is not working in Internet Explorer & Mozilla but works fine in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am taking session attribute in my javascript and then using it in if-else.
The script is suppose to run whenever user some anchor tags click on anchor tag.

```
<a id="someId" href="/someurl" onClick="checkSession(this.id)">Link</a>

<a id="someOtherId" href="/someurl" onClick="checkSession(this.id)">Link2</a>
```

And within body

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkSomething(clickedId){     

        event.preventDefault();     
        var value= <%=(int) session.getAttribute("key")%>;

        if(value != -1){
            window.location = $('#'+clickedId).attr('href');
        }else {
            alert("Please Select a value first then click on the link.");
            $("#someInput").focus();
        }

    };


</script>
```

Script runs perfectly on chrome but fails on mozilla and IE.
On mozilla I can see that anchor tags has been bind with that javascript but yet it does not run.

Comment: You've to pass the `event` object from inline handlers. If you'll take a look at the console, you'll find "event is undefined" error. Looks like you'd use jQuery, why don't you assign events by jQuery?

Comment: Thanks understood the mistake!!! Though It would be nice if It would hv worked anyways,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the event instead of the ID. Also, you don't need jQuery to get the `href` of the element. Just use vanilla JavaScript:

```
<a id="someId" href="/someurl" onClick="checkSession(event)">Link</a>   
<a id="someOtherId" href="/someurl" onClick="checkSession(event)">Link2</a>

<script>
    function checkSession(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clickedId = event.target.id;
        var href = event.target.href; 

        // etc
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks understood the mistake!!! Though It would be nice if It would hv worked anyways,

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can:

```
<a id="someId" href="javascript:checkSession('/someurl')">Link</a>   
<a id="someOtherId" href="javascript:checkSession('/someOtherurl')">Link2</a>

<script>
    function checkSession(url) {
      var value= <%=(int) session.getAttribute("key")%>;

      if(value != -1){
          window.location = url;
      } else {
          alert("Please Select a value first then click on the link.");
          $("#someInput").focus();
      }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't use `javascript:` protocols. Instead bind handlers with `addEventListener` or use some tool like jQuery.

Comment: An anchor tag which has an HREF attribute has a default EventHandling to go to HREF specified. By using onclick you have to override the default behaviour of the anchor tag. javascript: is a fully supported feature by all browsers and has been for a couple of decades.  If you solely want to use onclick  use a button and style it to look like an anchor tag. In this case you are doing extra work and overriding the default behaviour of the anchor tag needlessly.

Comment: I understand that you'll need to prevent the default action, but doing that is far better than using the JavaScript protocol. With all due respect, the extra work (not much work, to be honest) is far better than perpetuating a bad pattern.